# Preventing a draft email from being sent

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Is there a way to mark an email as "incomplete" or "draft" in Outlook 07 so I cannot accidentally send it while I am still making changes to it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We use something similar to the following script in Outlook 2003: -

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    'Ignore Non Email Objects
    If Item.Class <> olMail Then Exit Sub

    'Prevent Sending of email with the word Draft in the Subject
    If InStr(1, Item.Subject, "draft", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Ans = MsgBox("You are not permitted to send Draft Emails", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Draft Emails")
        Cancel = True
    End If

End Sub
```

I should add that it looks for the word **Draft** in the Message Subject and if found it will prevent the sending of the email.

Comment: This is pretty sweet: should save me from sending some incomplete emails!

Comment: How do I add such a script to Outlook?

Comment: Hold down Alt and Press F11 - This should bring up the VB Editor which you can paste the code into.

Comment: The version of the script we use simply searches for the words attached or attachment and then if the message has no attachment it prompts for confirmation of sending without an attachment.

The amount of times this has saved me from sending an email referring to an attachment which I haven't actually added is embarrassing.

Comment: @Paul, please see hazel's question in the answer at http://superuser.com/questions/10076/preventing-a-draft-email-from-being-sent/62184#62184 -- thanks!

Answer (score 5):

After being bitten once, I only address an email **after** I have finished writing it.

Answer (score 3):

I **add garbage** to the CC: line, like "ZZZ".  Outlook won't send it that way.

This way you still get to prepare the To line with the proper recipients while composing the mail.

I also tell Outlook to delay all outgoing messages by 2 minutes, as I often remember something important just after I hit Send.

Comment: Thanks. This works in Thunderbird too.

Answer (score 0):

Set it to spellcheck all e-mails - chances are that there's something in there which it will catch.  If in doubt make sure something in your signature isn't in the dictionary...